# How do I check to see if my AzureAD version is V1 or V2?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

Where would I look to check the AzureAD version? Is there some command line utility that would return the version, or some rest endpoint that gives basic information like that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Azure AD itself is versionless. What can be v1 or v2 is the endpoint and app registration with which you talk to it.**

Check out the docs on [the v2 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview) and [a v1 vs v2 comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare)

For most URLs (metadata, authorize, token), you can tell based on whether it contains /v2.0/ for example:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` is v1 whereas
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` is v2

**EDIT** - Including extra data points provided by Daniel

The version of your Azure AD application depends on what portal was used to register it,

- If in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), then it's a v1 application.
- If in the [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) then it's a v2 app.

Comment: Great answer here.  To checkout which endpoints your app is using, you can use a network tracing tool like fiddler or look at the URL your app redirects to on sign in. Another way to find out is from the portal you registered your application.  If you did it in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), then it's a v1 application. If you did it in the [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) the it's a v2 app.

Comment: Well.. AAD probably has a version, but it's not like it matters to anyone outside MSFT :) And it's not related to v1 and v2, which are the endpoints.

Comment: Now, `App Registration Portal` is no longer available to register and manage converged applications. Microsoft recommends that ​you manage your existing applications and register new applications by using the App registrations in the Azure portal itself. ​