# How do I check to see if my AzureAD version is V1 or V2? with middle ware

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, adal

[AZURE AD V1 V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987516/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-my-azuread-version-is-v1-or-v2/72445068#72445068) 
above all agree but v1.0 tokens contain both the x5t and kid claims, v2.0 tokens contain only the kid claim. and i m using ISecurityTokenValidator custom token validator

public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)

var principal = _tokenHandler.ValidateToken(securityToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

will this be going to be impacted ?? after i will start using V2 end point and token ??

Answer (score 0):

Token validation will keep working fine. [You might need to change JWT claim type mapping though](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4660).